# Is there a Linux cursor that has a (semi-transparent) Halo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, mouse-cursor

There are certainly a LOT of Linux cursor themes out there. My problem is that most are useless for me as I'm partially sighted. Limited time means I can't try them all, either.

The biggest problem for me is seeing the I-beam on almost any background. Just making it bigger is pointless as it gets so big you can't tell which line it is sitting in or between which letters it's positioned..

One idea I had was to have the cursor, at least the I-beam, sitting in a "halo", a color-configurable, transparency-adjustable background about the size of a quarter (also adjustable?). The idea is, I can see the colored circle, say bright green on the white background, and know that the font-size-appropriate I-beam is in the middle of it.

Does anyone know of such a cursor or a really good set of instructions for doing it myself? My system is Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity COMPLETELY REMOVED.  My login-time desktop choice is "gnome".  Compiz is installed, but says it's not the running manager.  Ditto gnome-panel.

NOTE:  I cross posted here from StackOverflow when someone decided this was a better forum for this discussion.